# Footnotes: Is it possible to combine "para" and "standard" style with one counter?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I know the para option of the `footmisc` package. I also know how to define seperate kinds of footnotes with `manyfoot` and that this package has the para option as well.

I am looking for a way to combine standard and para footnotes within the same counter in order to swith between them. Why? There is a scientific essay with some long footnotes and a lot of simple page-numbers or "ibd."s.

That is why I am imagining something like:

> (1) long footnote long footnotelong footnotelong footnotelong
> footnotelong footnotelong footnotelong footnotelong footnotelong
> footnotelong footnotelong footnotelong footnote (Kruger 2011, 65).
>
> (2) Ibd. (3) Ibd. (4) Ibd.
>
> (5) next long footnotenext long footnotenext
> long footnotenext long footnotenext long footnotenext long
> footnotenext long footnotenext long footnotenext long footnote.

PS: No, right at this moment it is no option to place the ibd.s in brackets in the main text.

Comment: The package `bigfoot`, which is in many ways an improvement of `manyfoot`, tries to do this automatically for the `para` option.  Unfortunately, it is not perfect.  In my opinion, this is a real desideratum for footnotes in LaTeX, but, even more unfortunately, I'm not the person likely to solve this problem...  However, your question just shows plain paragraphed footnotes, which is at odds with your question.  Should the "(1) ... long footnote." paragraph be changed..?

Comment: Thank you, jon, I will give bigfoot a try and then reply (I just edited my example to fit my question).

Comment: Yes, `bigfoot` does what i want, I even found out that I can determine to begin a new paragraph with `\footnote+{}`. Do you know how to do the opposite, to determine that a note should be set in the same paragraph (instead of beginning a new one)? I did not find this case.

Comment: No, I don't think so, which is one reason why it is not ideal.  Essentially, it calculates the badness of running things together and comes to its own conclusions, and it is not easy at all to modify its opinions.  I wish there were some user-level settings to interact with, but there aren't.  (Though I haven't actively used `bigfoot` recently.)

Comment: I share your wish ... Thank you very much, once again. As we just exchanged comments, I don't think there is a way to say "thank you" by accepting your answer or sth. like that?

Comment: I think the best options are to delete the question, or your or I provide it with an answer; otherwise, it just becomes one more unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

[jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8528/jon) showed me the right direction (see comments above): the [`bigfoot`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot/) package allows `para` as option and switches automatically between standard- und para-style footnotes.